# asp.net gridview radio button

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radio-button

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-radio-buttons-cs

Please refer the above link. How to select the RadioButton programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void SetPrimaryContactID()
{
    if (grvCustomerContact.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gr in grvCustomerContact.Rows)
        {
            Label l = (Label)gr.FindControl("lblContacts_ID");
            bool s = hd_PrimaryContact.Value.Equals(l.Text);
            if (hd_PrimaryContact.Value.Equals(l.Text))
            {
                Literal output = (Literal)gr.FindControl("RadioButtonMarkup");
                output.Text = string.Format(@"<input type='radio' name='PrimaryConactGroup'" + @"id='RowSelector{0}' value='{0}' checked='checked' />", gr.RowIndex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer as correct (using green tick to the left)